# Limit posts per author role (excluding admin) in home page

Tags: posts, author, homepage, limit

I have multiple authors in my site and want to show just one, the **latest** post from each one, excluding the administrators. So, if for example:

- admin1 has posted 4 posts
- admin2 posted 3 posts
- author1 posted 2 and
- author2 posted 7,

it will show 4 from admin1, 3 from admin2 and 1 from each one of the others. Any hints?

```
<?php 
get_header(); 
//Displaying latest post per author on front page 
if(have_posts()) : 

    get_template_part('content', 'postlist'); 

else : 
    get_template_part('content', 'none'); 
endif;

get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem then this should definitely work.

```
<?php 
get_header();

$users = get_users( array( 'who' => 'author' ) );//get all the users with author role in an array


foreach ( $users as $user ) {   //travers the array

    if($user->caps['administrator']==1)continue;     // skip the user if user also have administrative capabilities
$query = new WP_Query( array(
                            'posts_per_page'=>1, 
                            'author' => $user->ID
                            ) 
                    );
if($query->have_posts()):while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();

get_template_part('content', 'postlist'); 

endwhile;

else:
get_template_part('content', 'none'); 
endif;

} 

get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it doesn't seem to work.
in my index.php i have the following:
`<?php
 get_header();
 //Displaying latest post per author on front page

 if(have_posts()) :
 
  get_template_part('content', 'postlist');

 else :
 
  get_template_part('content', 'none');
 
 endif;

 get_footer();
?> `

Comment: @maus didn't u try my code??

Comment: @maus  i have edited my answer , give it a try , this should definitely work

Comment: First, I think the bracket } is not correct and it should be placed before  `if($query->have_posts())` as it displays the whole output multiple times (equal to number of authors). 
Second, if I remove the `if($user->caps['administrator']==1)continue; ` it is supposed to display just one post per author (regardless if it is a admin or not), right? Well, I see no change on the final output. Everything is displayed.